# Garry's Mod Blue Loading Screen Crash

Tags: resolution, steam

My Garry's Mod on Steam keeps crashing. When I click play it pops up with the blue screen with the Loading tag on the bottom right. It's not on full resolution but I don't know how to set it to full screen resolution, which I believe might be part of the problem, and I have tried reinstalling the game and steam.

I have also tried different Launch Options
like `-dxlevel 81`. I have also tried to identify the problem with `-condebug` but nothing works!

*How should I proceed?*

Comment: Using -dxlevel 81 won't help you with any game on GNU/Linux. That is a parameter for DirectX, and pretty much every Steam game for GNU/Linux uses OpenGL, including Garry's Mod. Using a DirectX-related parameter won't do anything or might make things worse. (I thought I'd tell you that so you know in the future.)

Comment: Can you please include any relevant log files or program output so we might learn more about this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Judging by [this GitHub bug report](https://github.com/Facepunch/garrysmod-issues/issues/1833) it looks like Garry's Mod has been broken on Linux for more than a week now. There doesn't seem to be any proper workaround available. You will probably have to wait for a patch to address this issue.